# HTML footer not aligning beneath both tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

When using the below code on my local server it looks like this:

[image]

I want the footer to be aligned from left to right, filling the whole page, not aligning up halfway to the table aligned left. So fully 100% width.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, am I overlooking something?

What I've tried:

- I checked the `<table></table>` tags
- I checked the `<th></th>` and `<tr></tr>` tags
- I have checked the footer and the `<p></p>`
- When removing the table aligning left the issues seems to be resolved
- When removing the table aligning center the issues remains

```css
body {
    Helvetica,
    Arial,
    sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}

p {
    /* 1.5em;*/
    font: 20px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    /* fallback color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
}

table.invoice_main {
    color: #333;
    width: 250x;
    Helvetica,
    Arial,
    sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table.invoice_main td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    height: 30px;
}

table.invoice_main th {
    background: #F3F3F3;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.invoice_main td {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 7px;
}

table.list {
    color: #333;
    Helvetica,
    Arial,
    sans-serif;
    width: 800px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table.list td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    height: 30px;
}

table.list th {
    background: #F3F3F3;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.list td {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<p>Invoice - Add</p>
<form method="post" action="add.php">
    <table class="invoice_main" align="left">
        <tr>
            <th>Invoice to</th>
            <th>Invoice address</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="view.png" alt="Invoice to" width="15px" height="15px"> Name:
                <input type="text" required name="name">
            </td>
            <td><img src="address.png" alt="Address" width="15px" height="15px"> Address:
                <input type="text" required name="address">
                <br> Postalcode:
                <input type="text" required name="postalcode">
                <br>Place:
                <input type="text" required name="place">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="list" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>#</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="calendar.png" alt="Calendar" width="15px" height="15px"> Date:
                <input type="date" style=" Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" name="date" required>
            </td>
            <td><img src="description.png" alt="Description" width="15px" height="15px"> Description:
                <input type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" name="description">
            </td>
            <td><img src="amount.png" alt="Amount" width="15px" height="15px"/> Amount:
                <input type="number" placeholder="€0,01" required name="amount" min="0.01" step="0.01" max="10000">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="+">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<p>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</p>
```

Comment: You need to give us a demo that reproduces the problem, not just your CSS. See how to create a [mcve]. And please update your post to ask a clear, specific question, not just "page acting up". We don't know how it's supposed to look.

Comment: Include the relevant code in the post itself, not just a link to pasted code.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks for the reply, I was editing my post, before you make your assumptions have a little patience lol. I can't include it, pasting it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Here you go, sorry for the long wait.

Comment: You're missing the closing tag in the last <td>, should be: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="+>`

Comment: @Darren Thank you for noticing, I have changed this but my problem persists.

Comment: What is your specific question? "HTML Table aligning" is not a question...

Comment: @Darren I'll change my title. the footer as u can see aligns next to the table which I aligned left. I want it to be beneath both of the above tables.

Comment: So, we can see what your table looks like, but you haven't described what it's *supposed* to look like.

Comment: @JDB as I've said in the post mentioning Darren, I want the footer to be aligned properly beneath both tables from left to right, not aligning half next to the left table.

Comment: Did you actually write your code without indentation, or is it a result of your code-pasting-issues?

Comment: @J.Starick It is indeed an result of my code-pasting-issues. I am truly sorry.

Comment: Snippet looks fine to me.

Comment: @Mike.Chun I thought the same until I made my window really wide.

Comment: To everyone above, thank you for the help.

Comment: For future reference: [comments are ephemeral](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341296/211627)... they can be deleted at any time without notice. Content critical to your question should be in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: `<footer>` is not a valid child of `<p>`; `<p>` elements can only contain phrasing contents. A `<footer>` is flow content. Web browsers will automatically close your opening `<p>` element before the `<footer>` appears, and your page will render this code: `<p></p><footer></footer><p></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: both` as a style attribute on your `<p>` elements.

Additionally, you were missing the `font-family` designation before the font names, and one of your widths was missing the `p` in `px`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Invoice</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Invoice">
  <meta name="author" content="Tredgy">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #333;
    }
    
    p {
      /* 1.5em;*/
      font: 20px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
      color: white;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: justify;
      background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      /* fallback color */
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      text-align: center;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    footer {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    table.invoice_main {
      color: #333;
      width: 250px;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
    
    table.invoice_main td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      height: 30px;
    }
    
    table.invoice_main th {
      background: #F3F3F3;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    table.invoice_main td {
      background: #FAFAFA;
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 7px;
    }
    
    table.list {
      color: #333;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      width: 800px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
    
    table.list td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      height: 30px;
    }
    
    table.list th {
      background: #F3F3F3;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    table.list td {
      background: #FAFAFA;
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 7px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Invoice - Add</p>
  <form method="post" action="add.php">
    <table class="invoice_main" align="left">
      <tr>
        <th>Invoice to</th>
        <th>Invoice address</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="view.png" alt="Invoice to" width="15px" height="15px"> Name: <input type="text" required name="name"></td>
        <td><img src="address.png" alt="Address" width="15px" height="15px"> Address: <input type="text" required name="address"><br> Postalcode: <input type="text" required name="postalcode"><br>Place: <input type="text" required name="place"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="list" align="center">
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>#</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="calendar.png" alt="Calendar" width="15px" height="15px"> Date: <input type="date" style=" Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" name="date" required></td>
        <td><img src="description.png" alt="Description" width="15px" height="15px"> Description: <input type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" name="description"></td>
        <td><img src="amount.png" alt="Amount" width="15px" height="15px"> Amount: <input type="number" placeholder="€0,01" required name="amount" min="0.01" step="0.01" max="10000"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="+"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <p>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will take this with me next time I have to ask a question. Was it because of the P I forgot or the clear:both because I need to understand what I did wrong.

Comment: The `clear: both` solved the problem. The other stuff I mentioned was just extra things I noticed.